# Set selected item in spinner

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I am doing an android application and for displaying the detail view of listed data,I need to set the selected item of a spinner.How can I set this?

I am new to android developing field..can any one pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Using the `setSelection(...)` method of the `Spinner` widget's class, the position of the selected item can be set.

For example:

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```